# MYSQL PHP Wildcards

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that's called by AJAX and it keeps not returning the wildcard results I'd like to see. Can't figure out what's wrong. Odd bit is I'm trying to look up unusual characters in the DB like `=.-,;,"` etc. The app I'm building is a English Character to Braille lookup.

Here's my code.

```
$ENG = "english phrase" // Could be Equal sign, dash whatever
$ENG_WILD = $ENG."%"; //Add in wildcard
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $DB_TABLE WHERE ENG LIKE '$ENG' OR '$END_WILD' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $DB_TABLE WHERE ENG LIKE '$ENG' OR '$END_WILD' ");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
    die($Failed . mysql_error());
}

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row
    echo $box."Dots needed for..".$row['ENG']."..are..".$row['BR_PAR']."..The Rule that applies..".$row['RULE']."</p>".$box_end;
}
```

I've tried using `*` instead of `%` but it fails. Here's an example of an entry in the DB  under ENG: `= (Nemeth Code: Equal Sign)`

If I run the script above with the input as a whole I get the proper result but if I run it with `=` or `= (Nemeth` I will get no results. I don't get it -- I would have thought the wildcard would have got me what I wanted. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is `$ENG_WILD`, but you're using `$END_WILD` in your `mysql_query()` function. (EN*G* vs EN*D*)

If you fix this and it's still not working, keep in mind that using `%` at the end will only match if the phrase comes at the beginning of that field.  Use a `%` at both the beginning and end to match if it contains your phrase at the beginning, anywhere in the middle, or at the end.

Comment: Nice Catch... Feel Like a complete Tard but the problem is still there

Comment: WAIT A MINUTE
If I put the % into the POST Search field manually it works fine; So somethings happening with the PHP when it tags on the % the SQL isn't recongnizing it right? Do I have to declare the % in some special way into the PHP String?

Comment: so if I put th% manually into the string that goes via POST to the PHP I get a proper response TH & THE Braille symbols.

Comment: I don't see any `$_POST` variables in your code.  Can you please update the original question or comment with the full code here so we can see exactly what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM $DB_TABLE WHERE ENG LIKE '$ENG' OR '$END_WILD'
```

Isn't probably doing what you think it is. With brackets, it's doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM $DB_TABLE WHERE (ENG LIKE '$ENG') OR ('$END_WILD')
```

When I think you want:

```
SELECT * FROM $DB_TABLE WHERE ENG LIKE '$ENG' OR ENG LIKE '$END_WILD'
```

It's also redundant to look for 'this' and 'this%', because the second will return 'this' as well.

You're also doing the exact same query twice for no apparent reason. I'm guessing there's lot of code we aren't seeing though.

Finally, having zero results shouldn't mean your query failed, there may just be no results for that query.